# What is the best way to change website contents without the user giving any trigger

Tags: android, ajax, database, changelistener

For example, whenever someone "likes" your post in Facebook, you get a notification. You don't have to refresh your page to get the notification. Or whenever someone sends you a message in Whatsapp you immediately get it.
How do they implement that? Does it use Ajax to listen for database changes every second or so?

I want to build an Android application which should do something whenever the value of a remote database changes. Should I use a service to check for the database value every second and compare it to the previous value? Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: I don't know if it is what you are looking for, but I think you can simply call a webservice every times someone is doing something that will change database, and from webservice send the notification to users. Is it possible for you? you will change the "send notification AFTER db changes" to "send notification AND change database"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either setup a gcm service or use the native android service to hit your database at a fixed interval of time . GCM would be more efficient and would be recommended , if your app is an extensive real time sort of an app like a messenger or something

Comment: I didn't know about GCM. This would make my job easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Google Cloud Messaging. But you will need a server to implement it.
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: I didn't know about GCM. This would make my job easier. Thanks!